# using primary keys in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, primary-key, clustered-index

when i create primary key on a column 'FirstName', is a clustered index automatically created for this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this is default SQL Server behavior.

It doesn't have to be that way - if you create your PK using T-SQL script, you can also choose to make it a **non-clustered** PK and put the clustering key on another column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(FirstName)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_YourTable
    ON dbo.YourTable(SomeOtherColumn)
```

In this case, `FirstName` would be the (non-clustered) primary key on your table, while `SomeOtherColumn` would be the clustering key for that same table.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you specify when you create the key. Indexes are automatically created for key constraints by SQL Server but as part of the constraint syntax you can specify either CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED.